# Update CoreData Object

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I'd like to update a CoreData Object. 
Backgrund: I made an app which includes a UITableView. In the textLabel of the UITableViewCell is a name. In the detailTextLabel of this cell is a date which can be changed/updated. Now I'd like to change this date.

I wrote the following code:

```
 var people = [NSManagedObject]()


 func saveDate(date: NSDate) {

      //1
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
      let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

      //2
      let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
      let person = people[dateIndexPath.row]

      //3
      person.setValue(date, forKey: "datum")

      //4
      var error: NSError?
      if !managedContext.save(&error) {
          println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
      }

      //5
      people.append(person)
      tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Now, if I run this code:
The date is successfully updated but the cell in which the date has been updated is displayed 2 times. For example if I added 3 cells and changed the date in the 3rd cell, I now get 4 cells displayed and 2 of them have the same content/are duplicated.

Does someone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding an additional object to your array each time. Your updated `Person` is already in the array and will display the new information when you reload your table data. To fix this, just take out this line:

```
people.append(person)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now the duplicated cell isn't showing up anymore. But if I added 3 cells and change the date of the 3rd the date of the 1st cell is also updated with the new date which should only set in the 3rd cell. If I relaunch the app all is correct (only 3rd cell is updated). Do you know why?

Comment: Where is the date coming from? I'll need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to associate some kind of unique identifier attribute to your `Person` class. This allows to retrieve that same object later using it identifier. I would suggest using a `UUID` string value, called `personID`, `identifier,` or something similar.

You can override the `awakeFromInsert` method on your `Person` class like so:

```
// This is called when a new Person is inserted into a context
override func awakeFromInsert()
{
    super.awakeFromInsert()

    // Automatically assign a randomly-generated UUID
    self.identifier = NSUUID().UUIDString
}
```

When you want to edit an existing Person, you want to retrieve it by the `UUID`. I suggest a class function like so (in the `Person` class):

```
class func personWithIdentifier(identifier: String, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Person?
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier ==[c] %@", identifier)
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1  // Only want the first result

    var error : NSError?
    let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [Person]

    // Handle error here

    return results.first?
}
```

This way you can use the following function:

```
let identifier = ...
let context = ...

var person = Person.personWithIdentifier(identifier, inContext: context)

if let person = person
{
  // Edit the person
  person.value = // change the values as you need
}
else
{
   // Person does not exist!
   person = // possibly create a person?
}
```